# Google map api stop converting address to lat & long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I am using below `google map api` for converting my address to `lat` and `long` and it was working fine  but suddenly it stop working don't know why is this happening.

```
{ string urlAddress = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?
  &address=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address) + "&sensor=" + sensor; }
```

Comment: maybe you reach the limit of free requests.

Comment: When you say `it stop working` - how exactly did it stop? Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: I have same doubt might be my free request limit gets over.do you have any idea how to make it working again??

Comment: Actually its not giving me any type of error but it stop generating lat & long from address.

Comment: You are allowed to do 2,500 calls/day, and I believe this quota get reseted on midnight pacific time (so, -7 or -8 depends on the daylight saving time). You can get a Maps for Work account that will give you more quota. Please also refer to [this section on quota](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Limits)